# Open facebook post/pageurl with facebook session within app in uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using latest `Facebook iOS Sdk` for Facebook integration. I am able to perform login and graph api/FQL operation very well. But now I want to open Facebook post/pageurl with facebook session within app in `UIWebView` after login. So, anyone know how to do it?

Comment: do you mean you want the user to be logged when you open the post in a web view ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD After user has finished login process via Facebook iOS Sdk, I need to open Facebook url in UIWebView with logged in Facebook session. So I need not to do Facebook login again within UIWebView.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you have to force Facebook webView login

```
// Initialize a session object
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
// Set the active session
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];
// Open the session
[session openWithBehavior: FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                            FBSessionState status,
                            NSError *error) {
            // Respond to session state changes, 
            // ex: updating the view
        }];
```

The webView based login will add some login cookies to your app (cookies manager)

**Next:** 
When you open post in webView load the cookies:

```
// req is NSURLRequest that you pass to your UIWebView
// this code should be before loading the UIWebView
NSArray *cooks = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]cookiesForURL:req.URL];
[self addCookies:cooks forRequest:req];
```

Here is the implementation for addCookies:forRequest:

```
- (void)addCookies:(NSArray *)cookies forRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
    if ([cookies count] > 0)
    {
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSString *cookieHeader = nil;
        for (cookie in cookies)
        {
            if (!cookieHeader)
            {
                cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@",[cookie name],[cookie value]];
            }
            else
            {
                cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@; %@=%@",cookieHeader,[cookie name],[cookie value]];
            }
        }
        if (cookieHeader)
        {
            [request setValue:cookieHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What If user did login via Facebook app/Safari/from device settings instead of UIWebView?

Comment: Then no cookies. The problem is you can not pass the session information into UIWebView @sunilz

Comment: Is there any way to force Facebook Login with permissions via Safari browser?

Comment: of course, you can find your answer here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/ 
What about what I provided above in my answer, did that help you ?

Comment: Yes, above answer will help, If I only need login. But If I need read/write permission with provided method by Facebook iOS Sdk, it will redirected to safari or Facebook app. Thats why I need to force login to Safari browser. Have you any solution? Also I have read given link by you, but I did not found way to force login via Safari.

Comment: use openWithBehaviour:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView

Comment: I want to achieve the same but FBSession is no longer available. How to to do this now?